# Вывод значения у child'а

Tags: javascript, html

Какая задача: сначала при помощи скрипта предоставленного ниже необходимо достать класс родительского элемента.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       
var parents = document.querySelectorAll('.card-item');
for (var i = 0, parent; parent = parents[i]; i++)
    parent.onclick = function(e) {
              if (e.target.className == 'btn popup-call')  { 
                  alert(this.className); 
                  var thunder = this.className;
                };

}
       </script>
```

Затем после этого необходимо спуститься к чилдам у этого родительского элемента и достать из него значения.

Код, который я предоставила, по нахождению родительского класса работает, а вот сделать спуск вниз к чаилдам не получается, чтобы я не делала.
Буду очень благодарна, если кто-то поможет с написанием кода, это очень важно для меня.

```
<div class="card">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>По вашему запросу подобраны следующие программы</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-slider">
            <div>
                <div class="card-wrapper-over">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="card-wrapper">
                            <div class="card-wrapper-inner" id="card-wrapper-first">
                            <?php query_posts_pfg(); ?>
                            <?php  /*$query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=program-card' );*/ ?>
                            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                                <?php while ( have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
                                <div class="card-item level-<?php $term_list = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'level', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
                                echo reset( $term_list ); ?> direction-<?php $term_list = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'direction', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
                                echo reset( $term_list ); ?> university-<?php $term_list = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'university', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
                                echo reset( $term_list ); ?> program-<?php $term_list = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'program', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
                                echo reset( $term_list ); ?> language-<?php $term_list = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'language', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
                                echo reset( $term_list ); ?>">
                                    <div class="card-item_top">
                                        <img src="<?php the_field('card_logo-link'); ?>" alt="logo">
                                        <p class="test"><?php the_field('card_title-rus'); ?></p>
                                        <h2><?php the_field('card_name-rus'); ?></h2>
                                        <h3>Основная программа <a href="<?php the_field('card_link'); ?>">О программе</a></h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-item_middle">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <p>Уровень обучения</p>
                                                <h3><?php the_field('card_level-rus'); ?></h3>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <p>Форма обучения</p>
                                                <h3><?php the_field('card_form-rus'); ?></h3>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <p>Код программы </p>
                                                <h3><?php the_field('card_code'); ?></h3>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <p>Продолжительность</p>
                                                <h3><?php the_field('card_during-rus'); ?></h3>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <p>Степень или квалификация</p>
                                                <h3><?php the_field('card_level-rus'); ?></h3>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <p>Язык обучения</p>
                                                <h3><?php the_field('card_language-rus'); ?></h3>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <p>Куратор</p>
                                        <h3><?php the_field('card_curator'); ?></h3>
                                        <div class="contact">
                                            <p><?php the_field('card_phone'); ?></p>
                                            <a href="mailto:<?php the_field('card_email'); ?>"><?php the_field('card_email'); ?></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-item_bottom">
                                        <div class="card-item_bottom-info">
                                            <h2><?php the_field('card_price'); ?>₽</h2>
                                            <p>за год обучения</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <a class="btn popup-call" href="#" onclick="checktest()">Поступить</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php /*wp_reset_postdata();*/ ?>
                                <div class="card-no-result">
                                    <h2>Нет подходящей программы?</h2>
                                    <p>Напишите нам об этом и мы придумаем для вас индивидуальное решение.</p>
                                    <a class="btn popup-call" href="#modal">Получить решение</a>
                                </div> <!-- card-item -->
                                <div>
                                    <li>Университет <div id="name"> </div></li>
                                </div>
                            </div> <!-- card-wrapper-inner -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- slide -->
        </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделал более-менее похожий пример на Ваш. Т.к. у Вас уже есть родитель, мы можем использовать `querySelector('.childClass')`, чтобы найти у родителя все дочерние елементы с нужным классом.

```js
const parents = document.querySelectorAll('.card-item');

for (let i = 0, parent; parent = parents[i]; i++) {
  parent.onclick = function(e) {
    const children = this.children;
    if (e.target.className === 'btn') {
      console.log(this.querySelector('.test').innerText);
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<div class="card-item">
  <div class="child">
    <p class="nested-child">Что-то другое 1</p>
    <p class="test">Нужный текст 1</p>
    <button class="btn">Найти значение</button>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="card-item">
  <div class="child">
    <p class="nested-child">Что-то другое 2</p>
    <p class="test">Нужный текст 2</p>
    <button class="btn">Найти значение</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ethithat, прости, что лишний раз тереблю и задаю тупые вопросы) 
Подскажи, а какой командой можно забрать именно текст без <p></p> , как ты указал в примере?

Comment: @АлинаСотская, `.innerHTML` lubo `.innerText`